# how can i run my scala code coverage fully

Tags: scala, microservices, akka-http

my scala code coverage report was 0.00% **(Akka-HTTP microservices)** and my report is

```
[info] Statement coverage.: 0.00%
[info] Branch coverage....: 0.00%
[info] Coverage reports completed
[info] All done. Coverage was [0.00%]
```

how can i run the my code coverage report 100%

am using this plugin **addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.1")** and in my code i don't have any unit test cases

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to be run, if you don't have any unit tests cases in your code?

Comment: for scala code coverage is it test cases mandatory  needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code coverage measures how much of your code is exercised by unit tests.  You can't get 100% coverage without writing unit tests.  Your question therefore reduces to "how do I add unit tests to scala code".

The simplest answer to this is to choose a unit test framework (of which there are a few).  I tend to use http://www.scalatest.org/, which is reasonably well documented, and you can follow its user guide for info on how to structure tests and so forth.

Comment: can u pls tell me, if I need to cover the 100% code coverage in scala, I need to write test cases only for services or I need to write for all methods(for all conditions) and services in Akka-HTTP microservices project.